# Is there a minimum compatible kernel version for each of the Ubuntu releases? Are older kernels compatible with newer Ubuntu releases?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, xorg, 17.10

Usually, building latest stable Linux kernel from source using the current kernel-config and installing them have worked just fine. In case of `17.10 x86_64`, the latest `4.x` kernels have worked fine - they have been taken directly from `kernel.org`. Of late, I am experimenting with older kernels like `3.x` and `2.x`. In that, so far, only `3.18.90` has worked with 17.10 except it had some issues with dual monitors which is not an important issue - might be Nvidia driver compatibility with older/newer kernels. But, all other older kernel versions like `3.2.97`, `2.6.39`, etc have not worked - booting gets stuck with "`.. Loading init ramdisk...`" screen. Examining the `journalctl` output for the specific kernel boot log didn't reveal much apart from some `X11` issue and some `systemd` services not getting started or were terminated. After digging through several websites on such `X11` errors, I enabled the `VGA VESA framebuffer` support, `console framebuffer` options in kernel-config. Still nothing helped. By the way, I did reinstall Nvidia drivers as well for each of these kernels before booting them afresh. So, is there any **minimum** kernel version for each of the Ubuntu releases? Also, I need to add that I tried using one of the old ubuntu-12.04 LTS kernel config to see if it makes any difference - didn't change anything with respect to getting stuck at "`Loading init ramdisk...`" Any thoughts on these?

Comment: Please improve your formatting; big walls of text are a pain to read.

Comment: Is there a point in this exercise? Older kernels are no longer supported once they reach end of life and shouldn't be used.

Comment: I am not sure anyone can tell you this as it depends on your hardware as, IMO, more than version of Ubuntu. Also we would need to know your hardware and config options, it is entirely possible you need to modify your config. And we would need to know how and why the kernel you compiled failed. This site is not conducive of such activity and custom kernels are poorly supported.

Comment: @Dr eval : As I mentioned, I am experimenting and researching on the older kernels compatibility with the latest Ubuntu releases. I know there is no official support from Ubuntu for kernels taken outside of Ubuntu repo. But, I wanted to see if there are any other people out there like me who would have experimented on similar lines with older kernels for their own research, curiosity, etc. As such, I am aware of the older kernels not having the latest bug fixes and I just toss away the ones that aren't stable. I constantly build and install the latest stable kernels as well.

Comment: @MichaelBay: Above reasoning explains the reason behind my experiments and research with older kernels.

Comment: @Ones who downvoted my question : These kinds of purely research-oriented and experimental questions need to be given the needed space. There's no point in downvoting them.

Comment: @RaghavanSanthanam Questions get downvoted for all sorts of reasons.  Your question is, as has been pointed out but not addressed, a "wall of text" that's unstructured and hard to read. You refer to "some issues" and problems with "some services" without specifying the issue or service so as it stands it's impossible to answer in any detail.  Questions are supposed to be specific enough to be useful to other users of the site and as it stands your question doesn't appear to fall into that category.

Answer (score 3):

> So, is there any minimum kernel version for each of the Ubuntu releases?

Yes and no.

Yes, in the sense that it is possible for a kernel to be too old to run a given Ubuntu release. New features are constantly added to the kernel, and if an Ubuntu release relies on some kernel feature, any kernel released before that feature was introduced will not be able to run it.

No, or at least probably not, in the sense that it is probably not feasible to find, for a given Ubuntu release, the earliest kernel version that is able to run it, as that would require testing every earlier kernel version against every possible use case. (Even if the kernel is able to boot a default installation of a certain Ubuntu release, it may not be able to perform every task like the official kernel for that release.)

Finally, a reminder that the only kernels that are guaranteed to work for an Ubuntu release are those that are in the official repositories for that release. You are free to try earlier (or later) kernels if you want to, but there is no guarantee of any sort (which is why no effort is made to determine the "minimum kernel version"; it would not guarantee anything anyway).